# Autohotkey - DoubleClick a Keystroke Combination to Run a Part of Ahk Code

Tags: keyboard, script, autohotkey

Is there a way to do a DoubleClick a Keystroke Combination to Run a Part of Ahk Code.

You can do a **DoubleClick** on any **Mouse** Or **Touch Device.**

But i Like to do a **DoubleClick** for All my **Keystroke Combinations.**

I am working on a Windows System, and i like **Autohotkey Languages.**

This is the code that i have so far, good idea's are always Welcome.

```
#SingleInstance force

esc::exitapp

;[Click one Time] - <Ctrl & c> to <copy the text to Clipboard>
{Ctrl}c:: ;Part1 Code.
sendinput ^c
return

;[Double Click] - <Ctrl & (2x)c>  <copy the text to Clipboard> + <do a Doogle Search>
{Ctrl}cc:: ;Part2 Code.
sendinput ^c
sleep 150
run https://www.google.com/?q=%clipboard%
return

;[a Count of Clicks] <Ctrl & (3x)c>
{Ctrl}ccc:: ;Part3 Code.
;?
return
```

Note - Hotkeystring <:*:{Ctrl}cv::> and Hotkey <{Ctrl}ccc::> does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do on your Windows System, DoubleClicks or MultiClicks for All the Keystroke Combinations to Run any Part of Ahk Codes, (Hotkeys cc::) - and if you want to use it also for (HotkeyStrings :*:cv::) you can change the Script a litte bit.

With these two Autohotkey Scripts you can do that.

- **1:** Does Copy automatic All Your Keystroke Combinations to a Single Windows Registry Key.    (you can run this in the Background)

[image: Display keystroke presses on screen from windows registry key]

- **2:**  You can then, use only that String Value from that Registry key, And write Codings to do Anything. (Note - This Simple Example Script will Show all your Keyboard &
  Mouse Movements on the Screen - and you can test it out with
  DoubleClick the keys Ctrl+(2x)c or MultiClicks 3x)

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER,software\GetKeypressValue,KeypressValue`

`DoubleClicks > if(KeypressValue="Ctrl + c, c")` or

`MultiClicks > if(KeypressValue="Ctrl + c (3)")`

[image: show keystroke presses on screen]

2 - You can Even Write Scripts From out other Languages. (you only need to acces that Single Registry Key.)

- Microsoft Visual Studio
- Visual Basic
- Turbo Pascal
- Delphi Languages
- C++
- Python Languages

**2 - DoubleClickForAllKeystrokes.ahk**

```
; [^ = Ctrl] [! = Alt] [+ = Shift] [# = Win]
; Press <esc> key to exit
; Press <f1> key to toggle between [Scan Pause] & [Scan] 
#SingleInstance force
Gui, +AlwaysOnTop -MaximizeBox ; 
Gui, Add, Text, center y10 h50 w300 vVar,  %KeypressValue%
Gui, Color, White
Gui, show
size=20
Gui, Font, s%size%
GuiControl, Font, var
Doloop=1

MainLanguages=us ; United States
TransLationTo=nl ; Dutch

GroupAdd, Browser, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1 ; Chrome or Iron
GroupAdd, Browser, ahk_class IEFrame            ; Internet Explorer
GroupAdd, Browser, ahk_class MozillaWindowClass ; FireFox
GroupAdd, Browser, ahk_class ApplicationFrameWindow ; Edge

While Doloop=1
{
RegRead, KeypressValue, HKEY_CURRENT_USER,software\GetKeypressValue,KeypressValue ; read KeypressValue


If not GetKeyState("Ctrl","P") and not GetKeyState("Alt","P") and not GetKeyState("LWin","P") and not GetKeyState("RWin","P")
{

;Note - All these Keystrokes will be execute after Release All the keys! 

;OneClick {Ctrl}+1x(c) - Copy Is the Default
;if (KeypressValue="Ctrl + c") ;use this for [1x=Ctrl + c][2x=Ctrl + c, c][3x=Ctrl + c (3)] [and many more]
;{
; Here you can put any Code. (Part 1)
; WriteReg_KeypressValue("OneClick - Is the Default Not Needed")
;}

;DoubleClick {Ctrl}+2x(c) - Copy + Google Search
if (KeypressValue="Ctrl + c, c") ;use this for [1x=Ctrl + c][2x=Ctrl + c, c][3x=Ctrl + c (3)] [and many more]
{
;Here you can put any Code. (Part 2)
;sendinput ^c ;Not needed comes from default. (OneClick)
WriteReg_KeypressValue("2x-Google Search")
If WinActive("ahk_group Browser")
{
sendinput ^c ;copy the selected text to clipboard memory
sleep 150
sendinput ^t ; CTRL+t make a new tab + goto address bar  - use CTRL+L for the active tab + goto address bar
sleep 150
texta = https://www.google.com/search?q=
textb = %clipboard% ;selected text
textc = &lr=lang_%MainLanguages%&hl=%MainLanguages%&num=100 ; google parameters

clipboard=%texta%%textb%%textc%
sleep 150
sendinput ^v ; paste the selected text 
sleep 250
send {enter}
clipboard=%textb%
} else {
sendinput ^c ;copy the selected text to clipboard memory
sleep 150
texta = https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&gws_rd=cr#q=
textb = %clipboard% ;selected text
textc = &lr=lang_%MainLanguages%&hl=%MainLanguages%&num=100 ; google parameters

clipboard=%texta%%textb%%textc%
run %clipboard%
clipboard=%textb%
}
}

;TripleClicks {Ctrl}+3x(c) - Copy + WikiPedia Search
if (KeypressValue="Ctrl + c (3)") ;use this for [1x=Ctrl c][2x=Ctrl c, c][3x=Ctrl c (3)] [and many more]
{
;Here you can put the Code For (Part 3)
;sendinput ^c ;Not needed comes from default. (OneClick)
WriteReg_KeypressValue("3x-Wiki Search")
If WinActive("ahk_group Browser")
{
sendinput ^c ;copy the selected text to clipboard memory
sleep 150
sendinput ^t ; CTRL+t make a new tab + goto address bar  - use CTRL+L for the active tab + goto address bar
sleep 150
texta = https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/
textb = %clipboard% ;selected text

clipboard=%texta%%textb%
sleep 150
sendinput ^v ; paste the selected text 
sleep 250
sendinput {enter}
clipboard=%textb%
} else {
sendinput ^c ;copy the selected text to clipboard memory
sleep 150
texta = https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/
textb = %clipboard% ;selected text

clipboard=%texta%%textb%
run %clipboard%
clipboard=%textb%
}

}

;MultiClicks {Ctrl}+4x(c) - Copy + Translate Text
if (KeypressValue="Ctrl + c (4)") ;use this for [1x=Ctrl c][2x=Ctrl c, c][3x=Ctrl c (4)] [and many more]
{
;Here you can put the Code For (Part 4)
;sendinput ^c ;Not needed comes from default. (OneClick)
WriteReg_KeypressValue("4x-TransLate Text")
If WinActive("ahk_group Browser")
{
sendinput ^c 
sleep 150
sendinput ^t ; CTRL+t this will [open a new tab] + goto adress bar
sleep 150
texta = https://translate.google.com/#auto/%TransLationTo%/
textb = %clipboard% ;selected text
clipboard=%texta%%textb%
sleep 150
sendinput ^v ; paste the selected text
sleep 150
sendinput {enter} 
clipboard=%textb%
} else {
sendinput ^c ;copy the selected text to clipboard memory
sleep 150
texta = https://translate.google.com/#auto/%TransLationTo%/
textb = %clipboard% ;selected text

clipboard=%texta%%textb%
run %clipboard%
clipboard=%textb%
}
}

} ;End GetKeyState


sleep 50
GuiControl,, var, %KeypressValue%

} ;End Loop


GuiControl,, var, "Scan Pause"
Gui, show

;-----------------------
~esc::exitapp

f1::
If Doloop=1
{
DoLoop := 0
}else{
reload
}
return

;-----------------------

WriteReg_KeypressValue(a)
{
RegWrite, REG_SZ, HKEY_CURRENT_USER,software\GetKeypressValue,KeypressValue,%a%  ;clear the KeypressValue
}
```

**1 - KeypressToREG.ahk**

```
; For the Changelog you can look to the Bottom of the code.
; This code works with a getkeyname from a Dllcall (See Bottom Script- by Lexikos)
; KeypressToREG.ahk comes from KeypressOSD.ahk that was Created by Author RaptorX
; you can press the esc key to exit.

#SingleInstance force
#NoEnv
SetBatchLines, -1
ListLines, Off

; Settings
    global TransN                := 200      ; 0~255
    global ShowSingleKey         := True
    global ShowMouseButton       := True
    global ShowSingleModifierKey := True
    global ShowModifierKeyCount  := true
    global ShowStickyModKeyCount := false
    global DisplayTime           := 2000     ; In milliseconds
    global GuiPosition           := "Bottom" ; Top or Bottom
    global FontSize              := 50
    global GuiHeight             := 115

CreateGUI()
CreateHotkey()
pre_prefix := "" 
prefix := ""
pre_key := ""
_key := ""
key := ""
return

OnKeyPressed:
    try {
        key := GetKeyStr()
        ShowHotkey(key)
        SetTimer, HideGUI, % -1 * DisplayTime
    }
return

OnKeyUp:
return

_OnKeyUp:
    tickcount_start := A_TickCount
return


CreateGUI() {
    global

    Gui, +AlwaysOnTop -Caption +Owner +LastFound +E0x20
    Gui, Margin, 0, 0
    Gui, Color, Black
    Gui, Font, cWhite s%FontSize% bold, Arial
    Gui, Add, Text, vHotkeyText Center y20

    WinSet, Transparent, %TransN%
}

CreateHotkey() {
    Loop, 95
    {
        k := Chr(A_Index + 31)
        k := (k = " ") ? "Space" : k

        Hotkey, % "~*" k, OnKeyPressed
        Hotkey, % "~*" k " Up", _OnKeyUp
    }

    Loop, 24 ; F1-F24
    {
        Hotkey, % "~*F" A_Index, OnKeyPressed
        Hotkey, % "~*F" A_Index " Up", _OnKeyUp
    }

    Loop, 10 ; Numpad0 - Numpad9
    {
        Hotkey, % "~*Numpad" A_Index - 1, OnKeyPressed
        Hotkey, % "~*Numpad" A_Index - 1 " Up", _OnKeyUp
    }

    Otherkeys := "WheelDown|WheelUp|WheelLeft|WheelRight|XButton1|XButton2|Browser_Forward|Browser_Back|Browser_Refresh|Browser_Stop|Browser_Search|Browser_Favorites|Browser_Home|Volume_Mute|Volume_Down|Volume_Up|Media_Next|Media_Prev|Media_Stop|Media_Play_Pause|Launch_Mail|Launch_Media|Launch_App1|Launch_App2|Help|Sleep|PrintScreen|CtrlBreak|Break|AppsKey|NumpadDot|NumpadDiv|NumpadMult|NumpadAdd|NumpadSub|NumpadEnter|Tab|Enter|Esc|BackSpace"
               . "|Del|Insert|Home|End|PgUp|PgDn|Up|Down|Left|Right|ScrollLock|CapsLock|NumLock|Pause|sc145|sc146|sc046|sc123"
    Loop, parse, Otherkeys, |
    {
        Hotkey, % "~*" A_LoopField, OnKeyPressed
        Hotkey, % "~*" A_LoopField " Up", _OnKeyUp
    }

    If ShowMouseButton {
        Loop, Parse, % "LButton|MButton|RButton", |
            Hotkey, % "~*" A_LoopField, OnKeyPressed
    }

    for i, mod in ["Ctrl", "Shift", "Alt"] {
        Hotkey, % "~*" mod, OnKeyPressed
        Hotkey, % "~*" mod " Up", OnKeyUp
    }
    for i, mod in ["LWin", "RWin"]
        Hotkey, % "~*" mod, OnKeyPressed
}

ShowHotkey(HotkeyStr) {
    WinGetPos, ActWin_X, ActWin_Y, ActWin_W, ActWin_H, A
    if !ActWin_W
        throw

    text_w := (ActWin_W > A_ScreenWidth) ? A_ScreenWidth : ActWin_W

    ;remove this gui codeline if you want only to Write the Value to Windows registry
    ;GuiControl,     , HotkeyText, %HotkeyStr%
    ;GuiControl,     , HotkeyText, %HotkeyStr%

    RegWrite, REG_SZ, HKEY_CURRENT_USER,software\GetKeypressValue,KeypressValue,%HotkeyStr%
     HotkeyText :=""

    ;remove this gui codeline if you want only to Write the Value to Windows registry
    ;GuiControl, Move, HotkeyText, w%text_w% Center
    ;GuiControl, Move, HotkeyText, w%text_w% Center

    if (GuiPosition = "Top")
        gui_y := ActWin_Y
    else
        gui_y := (ActWin_Y+ActWin_H) - 115 - 50

    ;remove this gui codeline if you want only to Write the Value to Windows registry
    ;Gui, Show, NoActivate x%ActWin_X% y%gui_y% h%GuiHeight% w%text_w%
    ;Gui, Show, NoActivate x%ActWin_X% y%gui_y% h%GuiHeight% w%text_w%
}

GetKeyStr() {
    static modifiers := ["Ctrl", "Shift", "Alt", "LWin", "RWin"]
    static repeatCount := 1

    for i, mod in modifiers {
        if GetKeyState(mod)
            prefix .= mod " + "
    }

    if (!prefix && !ShowSingleKey)
        throw

    key := SubStr(A_ThisHotkey, 3)

    if (key ~= "i)^(Ctrl|Shift|Alt|LWin|RWin)$") {
        if !ShowSingleModifierKey {
            throw
        }
        key := ""
        prefix := RTrim(prefix, "+ ")

        if ShowModifierKeyCount {
            if !InStr(prefix, "+") && IsDoubleClickEx() {
                if (A_ThisHotKey != A_PriorHotKey) || ShowStickyModKeyCount {
                    if (++repeatCount > 1) {
                        prefix .= " ( * " repeatCount " )"
                    }
                } else {
                    repeatCount := 0
                }
            } else {
                repeatCount := 1
            }
        }
    } else {
        if ( StrLen(key) = 1 ) {
            key := GetKeyChar(key, "A")
        } else if ( SubStr(key, 1, 2) = "sc" ) {
            key := SpecialSC(key)
        } else if (key = "LButton") && IsDoubleClick() {
            key := "Double-Click"
        }
        _key := (key = "Double-Click") ? "LButton" : key

        static pre_prefix, pre_key, keyCount := 1
        global tickcount_start
        if (prefix && pre_prefix) && (A_TickCount-tickcount_start < 300) {
            if (prefix != pre_prefix) {
                result := pre_prefix pre_key ", " prefix key
            } else {
                keyCount := (key=pre_key) ? (keyCount+1) : 1
                key := (keyCount>2) ? (key " (" keyCount ")") : (pre_key ", " key)
            }
        } else {
            keyCount := 1
        }

        pre_prefix := prefix
        pre_key := _key

        repeatCount := 1
    }
    return result ? result : prefix . key
}

SpecialSC(sc) {
    static k := {sc046: "ScrollLock", sc145: "NumLock", sc146: "Pause", sc123: "Genius LuxeMate Scroll"}
    return k[sc]
}

; by Lexikos - https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/110808-getkeyname-for-other-languages/#entry682236
GetKeyChar(Key, WinTitle:=0) {
    thread := WinTitle=0 ? 0
        : DllCall("GetWindowThreadProcessId", "ptr", WinExist(WinTitle), "ptr", 0)
    hkl := DllCall("GetKeyboardLayout", "uint", thread, "ptr")
    vk := GetKeyVK(Key), sc := GetKeySC(Key)
    VarSetCapacity(state, 256, 0)
    VarSetCapacity(char, 4, 0)
    n := DllCall("ToUnicodeEx", "uint", vk, "uint", sc
        , "ptr", &state, "ptr", &char, "int", 2, "uint", 0, "ptr", hkl)
    return StrGet(&char, n, "utf-16")
}

IsDoubleClick(MSec = 300) {
    Return (A_ThisHotKey = A_PriorHotKey) && (A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < MSec)
}

IsDoubleClickEx(MSec = 300) {
    preHotkey := RegExReplace(A_PriorHotkey, "i) Up$")
    Return (A_ThisHotKey = preHotkey) && (A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < MSec)
}

HideGUI() {
    Gui, Hide
}

~esc::exitapp 

;---------------------------------------------
; ChangeLog : v2.22 (2017-02-25) - Now pressing the same combination keys continuously more than 2 times,
;                                  for example press Ctrl+V 3 times, will displayed as "Ctrl + v (3)"
;             v2.21 (2017-02-24) - Fixed LWin/RWin not poping up start menu
;             v2.20 (2017-02-24) - Added displaying continuous-pressed combination keys.
;                                  e.g.: With CTRL key held down, pressing K and U continuously will shown as "Ctrl + k, u"
;             v2.10 (2017-01-22) - Added ShowStickyModKeyCount option
;             v2.09 (2017-01-22) - Added ShowModifierKeyCount option
;             v2.08 (2017-01-19) - Fixed a bug
;             v2.07 (2017-01-19) - Added ShowSingleModifierKey option (default is True)
;             v2.06 (2016-11-23) - Added more keys. Thanks to SashaChernykh.
;             v2.05 (2016-10-01) - Fixed not detecting "Ctrl + ScrollLock/NumLock/Pause". Thanks to lexikos.
;             v2.04 (2016-10-01) - Added NumpadDot and AppsKey
;             v2.03 (2016-09-17) - Added displaying "Double-Click" of the left mouse button.
;             v2.02 (2016-09-16) - Added displaying mouse button, and 3 settings (ShowMouseButton, FontSize, GuiHeight)
;             v2.01 (2016-09-11) - Display non english keyboard layout characters when combine with modifer keys.
;             v2.00 (2016-09-01) - Removed the "Fade out" effect because of its buggy.
;                                - Added support for non english keyboard layout.
;                                - Added GuiPosition setting.
;             v1.00 (2013-10-11) - First release.
;--------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not really straightforward, but it can be done with effort.

In your example, for the first two parts of it, where you are sending ^c in both cases, I have implemented something very close to this for copying hidden text in Word.  For that usage case, it doesn't matter if the ^c executes on each keystroke and then for "part 2", if the second ^c came within what you might deem the "double-click time"--which is bad nomenclature since no one is clicking anything--then the hidden text would get copied as well.  I will call it a "double-press time", vs. a double-click time, and in any case a good starting value is around 500ms.

**Example 1**

So in my code, if I press ^c once, it copies.  If I press ^c a second time, within 500ms, it copies hidden text (i.e., a double-press).  If I press ^c a second time but it was >500ms since the last press, then it just copies again (no harm no foul).

To do this, you create a function that gets called for the ^c hotkey (which is a key-blocking hotkey, i.e., it does not have a tilde).  Inside the function, a static variable is used to track the last execution time, and then compared to the current execution time.  Based on the results of the comparison, it either sends ^c or calls whatever other code you want to execute (or does both).  So this would work for the first 2 parts of your code above.

**Optimal Time for Copy/Paste**

By the way, you can also clear the clipboard prior to the copy and then use `ClipWait` in order to minimize the dynamic wait time it will take for the copied content to appear on the clipboard.  This is the best of both worlds for minimum delay and maximum reliability.

**Example 2**

Another doable implementation which is slightly different, is to use the modifier+keystroke (with a blocking hotkey definition) to call a function that counts how many times the keystroke gets pressed before you release the modifier.  In the Example 1, ^c executes as soon as you *press* ^c.  In this example that follows, ^c wouldn't get sent until you *released* ^c.

So for Example 2...

- If your keystroke sequence was `{Ctrl Down}{c down}{c up}{Ctrl Up}`, case 1 would execute
- If your keystroke sequence was `{Ctrl Down}{c down}{c up}{c down}{c up}{Ctrl Up}`, case 2 would execute
- ...
- If your keystroke sequence was `{Ctrl Down}{c down}{c up}{c down}{c up}{c down}{c up}{c down}{c up}{c down}{c up}{Ctrl Up}`, case 5 would execute

In certain cases where I use this for 5 or more options, I typically show a tooltip or GUI with which option is selected.  The initial hotkey triggers the tooltip/GUI to popup and selects option 1.  Holding down Ctrl (in this example) keeps the GUI showing and an option is not selected.  i.e., you have to totally let off the hotkey modifier (control) in order for the sequence to complete (slightly different from the above example).  As long as you have the modifier down, you can keep pressing the key and it will increase which option is selected, then you let off the modifier key to complete the selection.  For multi-press menus like this that use a GUI, I also have it loop the options, so if there are only 5 options or something, then if you get to 6 it just loops back to 1 and allows you to cycle options until you get the one you want.

This is better for certain things where you want to have multiple options by pressing the keys and don't need it to be as snappy, since it will wait until you've let off the keys to execute instead of (Example 1) jumping on it as soon as you press them.

So one way to do this is as follows:

First, you make a function that is triggered by your hotkey (^c example).  This function keep tracks of how many how many keystrokes are pressed by incrementing a static and/or global variable (depends on your code setup).

```
myOption := ((myOption="") || (myOption=0) || (myOption=6)) ? 1 : myOption+1         ; set comparison value to max number of options and this code will cycle through them
```

The ternary operator here just checks if we're initializing (variable null or 0) and will set to 1, or if we have reached our max number of options + 1, i.e., 5+1=6 for example in this case for 5 selectable options, then also reset to 1.  Otherwise (value after the colon), just increase the selected option by 1.

The first function also calls a second 'handler' function asynchronously via `SetTimer` (one-time call, so SetTimer will be used with some negative minimal value, say -100).  This allows the first function to exit so the main thread can continue to execute, while the second function also continues to run.  i.e., the second function can run while the first function is called over and over for each successive keystroke that meets the hotkey definition.  If you put everything into a single function, the execution doesn't complete the first time through and you can't detect successive keystrokes via the hotkey definition.  (You can still detect them manually but it's more straightforward to just use the pre-existing hotkey framework for detection)

The second handler function has two parts.  The first part is just a loop that checks whether your modifier is still down.  i.e.,

```
While GetKeyState("Control", "P")    ; wait for user to release modifier before continuing
    Sleep 10
```

Once the handler function clears the while loop--i.e., once you let off of the modifier key--all that's left to execute is whatever function code you need depending on which option has been selected.

This is selected using the variable that the first function increments each time the hotkey is pressed, i.e.,

```
If (myOption=1)
    function1()

Else If (myOption=2)
    function2()

...

Else If (myOption=5)
    function5()
```

For this to work you will also need to make sure that your `myOption` variable scope is appropriate between functions (shared or global).

**Escape Handler**

One last thing that I also do for this multiple-option setup, is to implement an escape option, in case I decide not to execute any of the options.  To do this I usually have a third function as an escape handler that is enabled as a conditional hotkey in the first function.

So for example, set up a ^Escape hotkey with code that will force an escape if modifier+escape is pressed.  This can be done by setting myOption=0 and sending `{modifier up}` in order to force the handler loop to exit, and then complete with no action.  This causes the handler to exit with no other action besides disabling the conditional hotkey for the Escape handler.

**Thread, NoTimers, False**

One final note is that you may need to use `Thread, NoTimers, False` in the first calling function, which affects subsequently launched threads, but is needed to allow the first 15ms/1000 lines of code to be interrupted immediately by another hotkey call.  If you don't have this, keystrokes may appear to get "dropped", or your mileage may vary on getting things to work.

Generally speaking, for all the bells and whistles AutoHotkey has, I haven't figured out a more simplified way of getting multi-keypress macros to work, but once you get something like this implemented in a framework that you can adjust to drop your various execution cases into, it will run very reliably.